# Get chrome extension activeTab permission from javascript with out a real click

Tags: google-chrome-extension

write an extension get the mediastream from current tab by using chrome.tabCapture.capture

In content-script.js, i send a message to background.js

```
$("video").bind('play',function(event){        
    port.postMessage("get-stream");

});
```

In background.js handle the message

```
function portOnMessageHanlder(message) {
   chrome.tabCapture.capture(config,function(stream){...});
}
```

but got an error

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabCapture.capture: Extension has not been invoked for the current page (see activeTab permission)
```

In manifest file grants the access permssion as follows:

`"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "tabCapture",

    ]`

also  check the chrome extension document , it says need to get active tab by browserAction,so i add setIcon when handler the message from content-script.js

```
            function portOnMessageHanlder(message) {
                if(message != 'get-stream'){
                    if(message == "set-icon"){
                        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
                            path: 'recordRTC-progress-1.png'
                        });                            
                    }
                    return;
                }                    

            chrome.tabCapture.capture(config,function(stream){
                        if(!stream){
                            return port.postMessage('PermissionDeniedError');                            
                        }
                        port.postMessage({stream:stream});
                });                                    
                return;
            }
```

but still got the permission deny error.

any advice ？ thanks

Comment: The accepted interactions are listed in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) (at the bottom).

Comment: Do you mean:
```
Invoking activeTab
The following user gestures enable activeTab:

Executing a browser action
Executing a page action
Executing a context menu item
Executing a keyboard shortcut from the commands API
Accepting a suggestion from the omnibox API
```

i already see these methods, it seems the browser action is UI operation not from code
can u give a example how to invoke activeTab from backgroud.js, i used to use 
chrome.browserAction.setIcon try to invoke activeTab

Comment: activeTab cannot be invoked programmatically. It is designed to represent real user interaction.

Comment: thank u, i tried to use command api to acitveTab, just simulate real user interaction

Comment: It cannot be simulated using chrome.* API. You'll need an external utility or automation tool.